# Check the content of file before upload

Tags: php, javascript, security, upload, zip

I have to check the Content of a zip/rar file before uploading to the server.

Let me explain the scenario.

There are 2 types of users in my web project:

1: Normal Registered user
2: Administrator of the Project

Any Registered user can Create Pages on our Project,also they can create `Themes` For Pages.

Here one of us suggested a feature that  to upload the `Theme` as theme pack [Compressed in `Zip/Rar` File].

If it is a Administrator then it is ok,there is no more security constraints.

But i am afraid in the case of Normal Registered Users.

My Problems are :

Assume that a Registered User uploading a theme pack that contains some malicious Files [Including PHP file] that may hurt the system.
I know that it is posible to check the Contents after upload,but what will happen if the use executed the File before that?

Ex : a user uploading a theme pack : contains `some PHP codes & other large files`,First our system will extract the content of the Theme Pack: Assume that the extraction of large files takes some time,and the smaller PHP file already extracted.So that the user can RUN the PHP file First.

The above one is my noob soubt,Actually i dont know other sides.

Please help me to figure out this problem.

Is it possible to upload the ZIP file in a secure manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to check this client side unless, of course, you had some kind of plugin (for all browsers) that did the checking/uploading for you.  You'll have to handle this on the server side.

Also, Admins can upload viruses just as easily as non-admins.  Some user's don't even know their machine has more viruses than a shanty-town brothel.

EDIT: Also, how is the user going to execute their PHP file on your server before you've checked it unless *you* run that php file?  This sounds like a recipe for disaster anyway.  All it will take is for something to slip through the cracks and a malicious user will destroy your site.  Allowing normal people to upload executable script to your server is asking for serious trouble.

Comment: Well,so is there any way to work this ??Admins are the power users of the project ,they have direct access to the server,so i dont care about Admins.

Comment: @DileepDil, you're asking the user to trust opening a file on their machine before it is uploaded.  For security reasons, this isn't going to happen unless you install a plug-in (which I am sure users aren't going to like).  As Nameless said, accept the upload, check it, delete/move it somewhere afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.I understood,But what will happen when a user/program executed the files immediately after upload ?

Comment: @DileepDil, see my edit.  The only way they can do that is if you execute the PHP file.  Put the files somewhere OUT of the webroot where they cannot be executed.  Check them there, then move them back once you're happy.  I still think this is dangerous, however.

Comment: A possible solution will be to upload the files and then someone (admin) needs to approve them (hard work). Or if you execute the zip contents in some kind of a sandbox, that is separate form your server where malicious users cant affect your system like a test environment

Comment: @ Moo-Juice I am saying that under webroot,so that the users can acces it through pages.Actually its not a php file,the way you suggested is look like good,but your last line discourage me,Why you think it is dangerous ?

Comment: @DileepDil, because you're allowing (even after checking), PHP code not developed by yourself and untrusted, to run on your server.

Comment: @ Moo-Juice No...its not like that...Be default there is no need of a php files...its just a HTML file and CSS,Images its enough for a Normal trusted user.Actually i am not going to execute the files directly ,i am reading the HTML content from the file and storing it on database.I told you that i have a HTML editor that placed on our project ,where users can edit their pages,its HTML content.But if you put PHP tags..it will not render ..it will show like text when we check the page source [i think that its happening on client side... ]

Comment: @DileepDil in that case, can't you just strip all the PHP out when the files are processed?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yeah its posible,i will remove all the `<?php` `?>` from the incoming HTML content.I am using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

Unpack it in directory, which can't be reached through the web, check, then move back to web-folder, where it should be.

Assuming that you have your website in directory /var/www/website and user content goes to /var/www/website/user and is reachable through www.website.com/user/ :

Create temporary dir in /tmp unpack there, check, move to /var/www/website/user

If you don't have access to /tmp, you can create /var/www/website/tmp and prohibit access to it using your server settings

Comment: Then how it is possible to access to a Normal User ??The theme pack contain a HTML files,Folders,Images etc..that which will be used in creating themes for pages.I have a HTML editor to create Themes,so that the user need to put the correct path to images there.If i uploaded this above webroot how it is possible ? and if it possible then other files are also possible .

Comment: @DileepDil Read again: after checking for malicious content, move unpacked files to where they should be.

Comment: Okkey,Thanks.Let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a folder for putting the zip file and unzip.

and disable the php execute for the folder. that can solve your problem