# Count a certain file type in a zip file using php

Tags: php

I want to be able to count a certain file type in a zip file with PHP.

I have zip files with files that have a .ppml extension contained in them and need to find out how many are in each file without unzipping them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233972/php-return-an-array-of-the-file-extensions-of-files-inside-a-zip-file